# how to zoom axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to add code in my function to zoom around a point, while keeping the option to un-zoom manually later.

I can use `set(gca,'xlim',[x1 x2])`, but if I later try to get back to the original zoom using the magnifier glass, the axes are "stuck".

Comment: try using the `zoom` function. or unset 'xlim'.

Comment: or use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10588 to do it interactively

Comment: bdecaf: this only enable/disable the zoom. Doesn't support defining the zoom area
anandr: I want the initial zoom to be made using code, not interactively

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as elegant as you want, but you can store the original axis limits:

```
plot(rand(100));
xlim_orig = xlim();
ylim_orig = ylim();

% Zoom to point ...

% Do other stuff

% Zoom back out
xlim(xlim_orig)
ylim(ylim_orig)
```

Once you have "reset" the axes limits, the manual zoom and pan tools will work as expected.